# How to control number of running threads in ThreadPoolTaskExecutor?

Tags: java, multithreading

I use `org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for executing my application tasks. I would like to limit number on parallel running tasks (threads) for some number and until all (or some percentage of running tasks) threads are done do not execute new threads.

How can I control, or how can I get information, how many threads does ThreadPoolExecutor is actually running to control executing new tasks? Is there some way how to solve it via ThreadPoolExecutor or do I need do it my way register new thread start and unregister when thread is done...?

Comment: "or some percentage of" <-- what do you mean? Doesn't an `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` fit your needs?

Comment: I mean that start new tasks / threads e.g. when 20% of previously started threads are done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getActiveCount()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#getActiveCount--) to get the current number of threads and [setCorePoolSize()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize-int-) to set the core pool size. You should set the pool size in your ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configuration. However I don't think waiting until all threads are done before starting new threads is how you should use a thread pool.

Comment: I think I need to control it because there is very large number of tasks (thousands of thousands) and I can kill or consume all server resources (however I haven't tested it). Is there a better way how to avoid this situation?

Comment: If you want to start new tasks only when 20% have finished out of, say initial 100, then setCorePoolSize to 80 from the beginning. It will limit the threads as you want.